# R - number of rows in which each unique value among certain columns shows up

Tags: r

I have the below abridged dataframe. There are additional columns in between the shown columns that I have not included:

| Case | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | NA |
| 2 | B | A | D | NA |
| 3 | C | D | A | NA |
| 4 | D | NA | NA | A |
| 5 | E | B | A | NA |

I would like to generate another data frame that counts the number of rows in which each unique value among certain columns (the ones shown) show up

| Type | Number of Cases |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 3 |
| E | 1 |
| NA | 5 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `unlist` the columns and get the `table` and convert to `data.frame` if we need a two column data

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(df1[-1]), useNA = "always"))
```

-output

```
  Var1 Freq
1    A    5
2    B    3
3    C    2
4    D    3
5    E    1
6 <NA>    6
```